# Copy Directory not work in C:\Windows\System32\spp\store

Tags: vb.net, copy, store

I am trying to make a copy of this directory from my program and when I try it tells me that, "the path does not exist".

Comment: Can you see the directory in File Explorer? Is it perhaps hidden using file system attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is a 32-bit app on a 64-bit system then you're experiencing what's called [**File system redirection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx).

Because 32-bit apps cannot load 64-bit dlls, and 64-bit apps cannot load 32-bit dlls, a 64-bit system has two system folders:

- `System32` - the 64-bit version with 64-bit dlls, and:
- `SysWOW64` - the 32-bit version with 32-bit dlls.

The File System Redirector automatically redirects `%SystemRoot%\System32` to `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` for all 32-bit apps trying to access the `System32` folder, so the reason you cannot copy the directory is because it doesn't exist in the `SysWOW64` folder.

There are three ways you can overcome this. I've listed them in the order where the first is the most recommended, and the last is the least recommended:

1. Use the `SysNative` folder instead.

   Instead of `C:\Windows\System32` you can use `C:\Windows\SysNative` which will take 32-bit apps to the *original* `System32` folder.

   ```
   If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True AndAlso Environment.Is64Process = False Then 'Is this a 32-bit app in a 64-bit system?
       My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\Windows\SysNative\spp\store", "your destination path here")
   Else 'This is either a 64-bit app in a 64-bit system, or a 32-bit app in a 32-bit system.
       My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\Windows\System32\spp\store", "your destination path here")
   End If
   ```
2. Compile your app in 64-bit mode or `AnyCPU`.
3. Disable File System Redirection by P/Invoking the [**`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743(v=vs.85).aspx). (I really do not recommend this as things might break if your app tries to load dlls from the system directory).

Comment: Oh, my God, thank you very much. It does work. I did not know the use of "SysNative". Thank you very much for your time and your special attention for the detailed answer.

Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jeremy : Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven't already, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It will only take a minute. ;)

Comment: Fact. Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I love StackOver. I have been following him for a long time, but today for the first time I needed to come in and ask.
I take this opportunity to thank all those who contribute little by little their experiences and help solve the problems that we started to walk.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\Windows\System32\spp\store", "D:\store", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please improve your answer; just dropping code is rarely good enough.