# Open a Windows cmd shell and run nbtstat via vb.net

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, visual-studio-2010

Sorry for the duplicate: the system migrated it over to this forum, even though someone here redirected me to there.

I'm making a program in Visual Studio with VB.NET and I'm having issues running nbtstat in a shell.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim A, IP As String
Dim B, C As Integer

...

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    B += 1
    IP = TextBox1.Text & "." & TextBox2.Text & "." & TextBox3.Text & "." & B
    A = My.Computer.Network.Ping(IP)
    If A = True Then
        'Process.Start("CMD", "/K nbtstat -a" & IP) NEEDS TO RUN AS A REAL CMD SHELL

    End If
    Text = "Pinging:" & IP
    ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, IP & " " & A)
    C = B / 30 * 100
    If B = TextBox4.Text Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
...

End Class
```

That is the small portion of code that handles the input.

Thrown error:

> 'nbtstat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> D:\Karanbir Ahuja\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NBTScan_Alpha.1\NBTScan_Alpha.1\bin\Debug>

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqWtN.jpg

I've had no luck with the fixes on that site, and I turned to here. The syntax seems to be right, but the shell is simply missing NBTstat.
http://prntscr.com/eg26jd

Even when sent to sys32.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi again! Over at Super User you should've just posted a question about the specific issue with `nbtstat`. Your code isn't relevant since it is the `nbtstat` command itself that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: If `nbtstat` doesn't work when you enter it manually in CMD then you should try yet another time asking on Super User - _**BUT**_ this time don't post your code nor even mention Visual Studio/Basic. Super User has nothing to do with programming, so your question must focus _**only**_ on the fact that `nbtstat` doesn't appear to work at all in CMD.

Comment: @VisualVincent nbtstat does work in a normal console, just not the one vb.net calls on.

Comment: But... That is impossible... It's the same console :/. Are you on a 64-bit system? If so then try starting the process `C:\Windows\SysNative\cmd.exe` instead.

Comment: Also, do check for Windows updates and install any new ones.

Comment: @VisualVincent Will try that path. As Far as Windows updates, I tore that out of this machine, but I couldn't get the program to work on a fully updated Windows machine.

Comment: Hi again! I might possibly know what this is about. If you are on a 64-bit system try `C:\Windows\SysNative` instead of `System32`. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42469331/3740093