# Running system restore (rstrui.exe) within vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, windows, cmd, system, restore

I have been trying to get the system restore wizard to start via my VB.net script but for the life of me it keeps saying "File cannot be found". Rstrui.exe is definitely inside the System32 folder and nothing seems to want to find it.

I even tried to open a CMD window and execute it via my application and still does not find it.

If you open a CMD window outside the application and type "Rstrui.exe" it starts it up straight away.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click


    Dim process As New Process()
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe "
    process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k rstrui.exe"
    process.Start()

End Sub
```

Even tried a start process rstrui.exe with this directory.

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86
```

Can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: FYI `SystemX86` is just the `System` folder, not `System32`. `System32` is actually for 64-bit applications (if you are on a 64-bit system), and will be redirected to `SysWOW64` for all 32-bit applications. This is most likely why it cannot find the program. See my answer in the question below:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy Directory not work in C:\Windows\System32\spp\store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467954/copy-directory-not-work-in-c-windows-system32-spp-store)

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent you hit the nail on the head my man.

Comment: Glad it worked! Good luck!